# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator Rdkit VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, rdkit

I'm trying to filter molecules from database 'part1' via Lipinski,Ghose and RUle of 3 filter but I keep getting error.
So, after I ran this script, I get an error 'object is not an iterator' at the line where 'progressbar' is mentioned twice. I'm new and would appreciate help.

Below is my script for filtering database of molecules.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors


import progressbar

if __name__ == '__main__':


    molecules = Chem.SDMolSupplier('chemspidersdf/part1.sdf')

    results = {
        "Lipinski Rule of 5": 0,
        "Ghose Filter": 0,
        "Rule of 3 Filter": 0,
    }

    print ("Molecule Database Length: " + str(len(molecules)))

    for i in progressbar.ProgressBar(range(len(molecules))):

        molecule = molecules[i]
        if molecule:

            lipinski = False
            rule_of_3 = False
            ghose_filter = False

            molecular_weight = Descriptors.ExactMolWt(molecule)
            logp = Descriptors.MolLogP(molecule)
            h_bond_donor = Descriptors.NumHDonors(molecule)
            h_bond_acceptors = Descriptors.NumHAcceptors(molecule)
            rotatable_bonds = Descriptors.NumRotatableBonds(molecule)
            number_of_atoms = Chem.rdchem.Mol.GetNumAtoms(molecule)
            molar_refractivity = Chem.Crippen.MolMR(molecule)

            # Lipinski
            if molecular_weight <= 500 and logp <= 5 and h_bond_donor <= 5 and h_bond_acceptors <= 5 and rotatable_bonds <= 5:
                lipinski = True
                results["Lipinski Rule of 5"] += 1

            # Ghose Filter
            if molecular_weight >= 160 and molecular_weight <= 480 and logp >= 0.4 and logp <= 5.6 and number_of_atoms >= 20 and number_of_atoms <= 70 and molar_refractivity >= 40 and molar_refractivity <= 130:
                ghose_filter = True
                results["Ghose Filter"] += 1
     
            # Rule of 3
            if molecular_weight <= 300 and logp <= 3 and h_bond_donor <= 3 and h_bond_acceptors <= 3 and rotatable_bonds <= 3:
                rule_of_3 = True
                results["Rule of 3 Filter"] += 1

      

    print (results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [progressbar2](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar). Looks like `progressbar` should be lowercase:

```
mols = Chem.SDMolSupplier('path/to/my/mols.sdf')
n_mols = len(mols)
for x in progressbar.progressbar(range(n_mols)):
    # do stuff...
```

It also works like this:

```
mols = Chem.SDMolSupplier('path/to/my/mols.sdf')
for mol in progressbar.progressbar(mols):
    if mol is None:
        continue
    # do stuff...
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped!

Comment: No problem. Please mark it as the accepted answer if it solved your problem, thanks.